# How to specific augmentation data types in mediapipe_model_maker?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, mediapipe, image-classification

I'm trying to use the image_classifier from mediapipe_model_maker to train a custom tflite image classification model. All I see for data augmentation is a boolean that can be passed in the options called "do_data_augmentation" that does random augmentation (cropping, flipping, etc.).

```
spec = image_classifier.SupportedModels.MOBILENET_V2
hparams=image_classifier.HParams(epochs=100, export_dir="exported_model_2",do_data_augmentation=False)
options = image_classifier.ImageClassifierOptions(supported_model=spec, hparams=hparams)

model = image_classifier.ImageClassifier.create(
    train_data = train_data,
    validation_data = validation_data,
    options=options,
)
```

I want to be specific about the data augmentation and keep only flipping, exposure and blur. Is that possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this date (latest version `0.10.9`), specifying custom augmentation is not possible (or not straightforward).

The flag set in the `HParams` object is used to set the augmentation flag for the `ImagePreprocessor`. To specify custom augmentations, you would have to subclass the [`ImageClassifier`](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/v0.10.9/mediapipe/model_maker/python/vision/image_classifier/image_classifier.py) to include your own logic, or to fork mediapipe and change the `Preprocessor` with your augmentations.

[Looking at the code](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/v0.10.9/mediapipe/model_maker/python/vision/core/image_preprocessing.py), the augmentations consist of:

- random flipping (left/right) (using [`tf.image.random_flip_left_right`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/random_flip_left_right))
- random cropping (the random cropping do not preserve the aspect ratio, so combined with a resizing, you also have a deformation of the image). (Using [`tf.image.sample_distorted_bounding_box`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/sample_distorted_bounding_box))

There is no exposure/blurring augmentation available in mediapipe. You would have to add that yourself.